# How do I stop a camera from rendering to a RenderTexture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a camera in my scene that has a Target Texture set as a Render Texture. I want that camera to render the scene into the Render Texture, but then stop rendering anymore, essentially freezing the frame into the Render Texture. How can I achieve this? Disabling the camera or setting its target texture to null seems to just make the Render Texture appear invisible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have like a snapshot function you could do it like this

```
public class SnapshotController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("If you want to capture a specific camera drag it here, otherwise the MainCamera will be used")]
    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;
 
    [Tooltip("If you have a specific RenderTexture for the snapshot drag it here, otherwise one will be generated on runtime")]   
    [SerializeField] private RenderTexture _renderTexture;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
    
        if(!_renderTexture)
        {
            _renderTexture = new RenderTexture(Screen.width, Screen.height , 24 , RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
            _renderTexture.useMipMap = false;
            _renderTexture.antiAliasing =1;
        }
    }
    
    public void Snapshot(Action<Texture2D> onSnapshotDone)
    {
        StartCoroutine(SnapshotRoutine(onSnapshotDone));
    }
    
    private IEnumerator SnapshotRoutine (Action<Texture2D> onSnapshotDone)
    {
        // this also captures gui, remove if you don't wanna capture gui
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); 
               
        // If RenderTexture.active is set any rendering goes into this RenderTexture
        // instead of the GameView
        RenderTexture.active = _renderTexture;
        _camera.targetTexture = _renderTexture;
               
        // renders into the renderTexture
        _camera.Render();
     
        // Create a new Texture2D        
        var result = new Texture2D(Screen.width,Screen.height,TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
        // copies the pixels into the Texture2D          
        result.ReadPixels(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),0,0,false);
        result.Apply();
       
        // reset the RenderTexture.active so nothing else is rendered into our RenderTexture      
        RenderTexture.active = null;
        _camera.targetTexture = null;
    
        // Invoke the callback with the resulting snapshot Texture
        onSnapshotDone?.Invoke(result);
    }
}
```

You would then use it like e.g.

```
// Pass in a callback telling the routine what to do when the snapshot is ready
xy.GetComponent<SnapshotController>(). Snapshot(HandleNewSnapshotTexture);

...

private void HandleNewSnapshotTexture (Texture2D texture)
{
    var material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

    // IMPORTANT! Textures are not automatically GC collected. 
    // So in order to not allocate more and more memory consider actively destroying
    // a texture as soon as you don't need it anymore
    if(material.mainTexture) Destroy (material.mainTexture);     

    material.mainTexture = texture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a snapchot of the actual render texture in the frame where you start freezing, get this image data and replace the render texture by an actual texture with this freeze image applied.